# Android Anko Radio Group with default value?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I'm writing an android app with Kotlin and Anko, and I'm trying to give the radio buttons a default value, but when I do the value never gets unselected. How do you set a default value that is changed when you click elsewhere?

```
radioGroup {
    orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL
    bottomPadding = dip(8)

    val radBut = { value: Int ->
        radioButton {
            text = "$value"
            onClick { Store.playerCount = value }
            if (Store.playerCount == value) {
                isChecked = true
            }
            rightPadding = dip(8)
        }
    }

    (2..5).map { radBut(it) }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't change isChecked property of radio button directly instead let radio group handle it by giving radio button id to radio group check(int id) method, please check this link for more details https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup#check(int)
and here's the code for you

```
   verticalLayout {
        orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL

        radioGroup {
            orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL
            padding = dip(8)

            val button1 = radioButton {
                text = "Button 1"
            }

            radioButton {
                text = "Button 2"
            }

            radioButton {
                text = "Button 3"
            }

            // Checking button 1 as default
            check(button1.id)
        }
    }
```